# Notify if there is an error in the macro in the excel file

Tags: excel, vba

Until now, if there is an error in one of the macro codes, it announces an error

I want instead to let him know he has to go to the manager

That's the code I have now

```
Private Sub Workbook_'What should be written here?()

    On Error GoTo error1
error1:
MsgBox "Error, contact administrator"
End Sub
```

How can I display the message in all errors in the file

If this is not clear enough, please write to me

Comment: What is the problem with the code? Also, can you share the code that you expect to through an error? You may be able to handle the code in the error

Comment: I can not imagine what my worker would do that could lead to an error,
So I want to have a message, instead of the text of the system that the employee does not understand

Comment: Does the workbook use any VBA code at all?  Or are you trying to catch any data entry errors to the formulas in the workbook?

Comment: I can post the message in any macro model, the question whether it is possible to write in the main file

Comment: *"I can not imagine what my worker would do that could lead to an error"* I mean you should write your code in a way that in **any case** no unrecognized error can occur. Good code doesn't throw any VBA errors at all. You should improve your code then or catch the specific error to handle it.

Comment: Lol just read my first comment. Too early. Throw error* and handle error* in code* smh

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend not using the `On Error GoTo error1` method of error trapping. You can trap expected errors directly rather a generic *'catch all'* approach.

Using `On Error GoTo error1` is error trapping your entire code. You won't even know what line threw the error which is problematic if your code is long.

---

Here is how you to correctly wrap your entire code in a generic *'catch all'* error trap. You need to use `Exit Sub` after your code. This ensures your error line only gets reached on the instance of an error.

```
Sub Generic ()

On Error GoTo error1

'Code goes here
Exit Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
error1:
MsgBox "Error, Contact Administrator"

End Sub
```

---

A better approach is to anticipate potential errors and code out the errors or handle them in a more direct approach. Since we do not know what error you are trying to trap for, I will just give one example. The below code aims to copy the last used cell in `Column A` and copy it to cell `B2`

```
Sub CopyRange()

Dim LRow as Long 'Last Row

LRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & LRow).Copy Destination:= Range("B2") '<---- anticipated error line

End Sub
```

This code will through an error if `LRow = 0` since there is no range `A0` to be copied. You could wrap your entire code in the generic error trap, or you could handle the error directly. Check the value of `LRow` and display your message there. Now you will know what the error is!

```
Sub CopyRange()

Dim LRow as Long 'Last Row

LRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Error Trap Here!
If LRow = 0 Then
    MsgBox "LRow Calculation Issue. Notify Admin!"
    Exit Sub '<---- code will stop here before the error has a chance to be raised
End If

Range("A" & LRow).Copy Destination:= Range("B2") '<---- anticipated error line

End Sub
```

Comment: Your example is a bit theoretical because I cannot imagine a case where `LRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` gives a result of `0`. But thinking theoretical: A row number must be positive and less than `Rows.Count` so I recommend to (theoretically) test for `If LRow <= 0 Or LRow > Rows.Count Then 'raise error` to exclude not only `0` but also all negative values and values greater than the maximum rows. So I could imagine that test eg for a `LRow` that comes from a user input.